# Can we make expectation arbitrarily small if $\sum x_i=constant$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

$X$ discrete, takes on finitely many values and the sum of these values are finite i.e. $\sum x_i=constant$ For every $\epsilon >0$ there is a probability distribution of $X$ s.t. $E[X]<\epsilon$.

Is this theorem provable? Can we make expectation arbitrarily small?

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for, but what would be wrong with $E[X]=0$, for example $X=\pm1$ with equal probability?

Comment: No, this is for every distribution of X whose sum of possible values is finite.

Comment: Then clearly not.  For example if $X$ can only take the values $22$ and $23$, with $22+23$ being finite, there is no distribution on this support such that $E[X] \lt 7$

Answer (score 0):

Sure, let $X$ be the deterministic constant $\epsilon/2.$ Or if that is too trivial, let $X$ be $\epsilon$ with $50\%$ chance and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: This constant shall not depend on $\epsilon $

Comment: A random variable cannot have several different distributions. In order for your question to be meaningful the random variable should be allowed to depend on $\epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

That's depends on the possible values of $X$. You can always create a probability distribution that matches $E[X] = \xi$ for any value of $\xi\in[\min X, \max X]$, conversely you can't have $E[X]<\min X$ or $E[X]>\max X$.

Assume that $\xi = (1-\theta)\min X + \theta\max X$ and let the probability of $\min X$ be $1-\theta$ and the probability of $\max X$ be $\theta$ and the other possible outcomes have probability $0$.

If the distribution shall not depend on $\epsilon$ we have to make sure that we can get $\xi\le 0$ which would need $\min X\le0$.

The converse is shown by just calculating the expectation:

$$\min X = \min X\sum p_j = \sum p_j \min X \le \sum p_j x_j = E[X] \le \sum p_j \max X = \max X$$

Comment: @monotonic May I assume that the question is more as follows: If $X$ is a random variable which takes finitely many values $x_i$ with minimum value $x_1$ (say) then $\forall\, \epsilon >0$ there is a probability distribution for $X$ such that $E[X]<x_1+\epsilon$, **independently** of $\epsilon$? If so skyking has given the answer. This is only possible if $X=x_1$ with probability one.